# Make Iferror and Googlefinance print "blank" cell if no value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-finance, nested-if, nonblank

Is there a way to make this formula print empty cells based on the "F" column having no value? I'm currently getting the cell to return "0" but I want it to be blank as I'm trying to combine this manual input with a supermetric query.
The purpose is to calculate the Avg. for that column and push it to data studio, if "0" exists the avg is wrong.

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(F2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:SEKGBP"),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(F2="",,IFERROR(F2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:SEKGBP")))
```